# Self join or Recursive query to get the count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, recursive-query

I have a requirement to group by rows where one value of a grouping set exists in another row. Like I have the below table

```
 | OrderID | ProductID |
 | 123     |    A      |
 | 123     |    B      |
 | 223     |    B      |
 | 223     |    C      |
 | 323     |    C      |
 | 323     |    D      |
 | 423     |    E      |
```

And I need the below. I have been thinking few ways but cant get anywhere. Any help please?

```
 |ProductId | NoOfOrders |
 | A|B|C|D  |     3      |
 |    E     |     1      |
```

Comment: Does that expected result really match the sample table data?

Comment: yep. so basically i need to get the count of orders by grouping  by products, but if the same product existt in another order they should be treated as the same. Its  a bit tricky to explain hence the above tables

Comment: Products A, B, C and D are together in order 123, 223 and 323. But you want 4 as NoOfOrders?

Comment: sorry @jarlh. updated my question. I would need 3 as NoofOrders. Thank you for that!

Comment: Could you please show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Well I have been trying to even think of it logically but cant get anywhere. I have got to this ` SELECT  ProductID, STRING_AGG (OrderID, '|') AS orders
 FROM sample
 GROUP BY ProductID `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. This starts with a simple grouping based on matching products, then uses a loop to recursively group things together until it can find no more merges to do:

```
CREATE TABLE #data 
(
    OrderId INT, 
    ProductId CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO #data (OrderId, ProductId)
VALUES (123,'A'),
(123,'B'),
(223,'B'),
(223,'C'),
(323,'C'),
(323,'D'),
(423,'E');

CREATE TABLE #data2
(
    OrderId INT, 
    ProductId CHAR(1),
    Grp INT
);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT OrderId,
           ProductId,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) r
    FROM #data
)
INSERT INTO #data2(OrderId, ProductId, Grp)
SELECT cte.OrderId,
    cte.ProductId,
    r
FROM cte

DECLARE @updates INT = 1;

WHILE @updates > 0
BEGIN
    -- join groups where there is a lower numbered group that it connects to
    UPDATE a
    SET Grp = b.Grp
    FROM #data2 a
    INNER JOIN #data2 b ON b.OrderId = a.OrderId
        OR b.ProductId = a.ProductId
    WHERE a.Grp > b.Grp

    -- end when we have done nothing this cycle
    SET @updates = @@ROWCOUNT
END

SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '|'+ ProductId                                  
            FROM   #data2 
            WHERE grp = o.grp 
            FOR xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS Products,
            COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderId) AS NumOrders
FROM #data2 o
GROUP BY grp
```